# Data upload error in QGIS cloud

Tags: qgis, connection, cloud-gis

I  want to publish my .shp file but I am facing one uxpected error.

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)    Is
>   the server running on host "db.qgiscloud.com" (136.243.87.197) and
>   accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/srap/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py",
>   line 695, in update_local_layers
>       self.update_local_data_sources(local_layers,  local_raster_layers)   File
>   "C:/Users/srap/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py",
>   line 737, in update_local_data_sources
>       self.update_data_sources_table_names()   File "C:/Users/srap/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py",
>   line 884, in update_data_sources_table_names
>       schema_list = self.fetch_schemas(self.ui.cbUploadDatabase.currentText())   File
>   "C:/Users/srap/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py",
>   line 1058, in fetch_schemas
>       conn = self.db_connections.db(db).psycopg_connection()   File "C:/Users/srap/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\db_connection_cfg.py",
>   line 165, in psycopg_connection
>       port=self.port   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2__init__.py",
>   line 130, in connect
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  Is the server running on host
>   "db.qgiscloud.com" (136.243.87.197) and accepting     TCP/IP connections
>   on port 5432?

can anyone help me to interpret this error?